# Approval Process when a checkbox is changed

Tags: process-builder, approval-process

I have a checkbox on account with active status. When someone edits the checkbox, an approval process starts and the manager needs to approve or reject. My issue is that this approval by the manager it could work both ways (if the checkbox is ticked=approved...if the checkbox is unticked=approved - for rejection as well), but in the approval process you can only specific for approval=tick checkbox and reject=untick checkbox). 
I also have a process builder when someone changes the checkbox, the approval is sent to the manager.
Can someone help me with a suggestion on what I can do to solve both scenarios? Thanks

Comment: If I understood you correctly what you need is 2 different approval process first will be triggered when that checkbox is checked the other will be triggered when the checkbox is unchecked so you can manage you approval or rejection actions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need two separate approval processes. One for approving or rejecting account marked as active, second for approving or rejecting account marked as inactive.

The corresponding approval action will be leaving the checkbox as is, and rejection action will be reversing it to checked or unchecked, according to which process we're in. Then, you can change your process builder to fire the right approval process depending on whether the checkbox was changed into true or into false.

Alternatively, you can use a hidden help text field or another checkbox field, that will indicate if the action taken was to activate the account or to deactivate it. Then you can use a single approval process the fires upon a change in the help field, and two different approval steps with approval/rejection actions, with a different entry criteria per the value in the help field.

Comment: Thank you, Eran, for your advice. I will give it a try to the two approval processes. 